# Calculating geographic distances in python

Tags: python, arrays, coordinates

I am new in python so I don't really know how to manipulate arrays.
I have a large JSON file than contains geographic location an example of this is:

> {"items":[{"language":"en","created":"2013-12-17T09:31:31.000+01:00","geometry":{"type":"Point","**coordinates":[9.2056232,45.4825264]**}

And also I have another file that contains coordinates i.e

> 4c29e1c197d00f47a60442ea,Area51Lab
>   Srl,4bf58dd8d48988d124941735,**45.44826958,9.144208431**

I want to calculate the shortest distance between coordinates in file 1 and coordinates in file 2 to generate a final file with the shortest distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from vincenty import vincenty

df1 = pd.read_json(data.json)
df2 = pd.read_csv(data.csv)

results = []
for i1, d1 in df1.iterrows():
    for i2, d2 in df2.iterrows():
         distances.append({
             "index1": i1,
             "index2": i2,
             "results": vincenty((d1.coordinates[0], d1.coordinates[1])                                     
                                 (d2.latitude, d2.longitude)) # you will need to adapt this part
         })

results = df.DataFrame(results)
results = results.groupby(["index1", "index2"]).results.min()

results.to_csv("results.csv")
# or
results.to_json("results.json")
```

[Vincenty's formula](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vincenty/0.1.4) uses a more accurate representation of Earth than Halversine's/Great-Circle so is generally more accurate.

If you don't have Pandas you should consider installing [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).  It's a Python distro for scientific computing and is all around pretty great – especially on Windows.

Comment: And yes I am going to use Vincenty.

Comment: @l4nd0 yeah it's not clear what the structure of your csv is from above.  Do you have a header line?  What is the error?

Comment: this the error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1: invalid start byte. The line is 

4c29e1c197d00f47a60442ea,Area51Lab Srl,4bf58dd8d48988d124941735,45.44826958,9.144208431

Comment: Actually my file doesn't have a header line, only the data @conner.xyz

Comment: @l4nd0 so then do `read_csv('data.csv', header=None, encoding='utf-8')`.  The columns will import with numbers for names this way, and then you would need to adapt the `d2.longitude ...` line to something like `d2[<num>]`.  You can always add a header line using a text-editor, or provide column names to `read_csv()` to avoid this.

Comment: @l4nd0 please consider accepting the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The group by is not working I have tried this `results = results.groupby(['index1','index2']).min()` but I got the same df before the group by  @conner.xyz

Comment: @l4nd0 see the edit: `groupby(['index1', 'index2']).results.min()`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to extract the latitude and longitude in your files. See json module for a json file for example. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

To calculate the distance between two points on a sphere given the angles (latitude and longitude...), you can use the haversine formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

There is a javascript implementation here http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html that you can adapt to python.